# How to save / read List <string> in XML?

Tags: c#

I try to save / read the List  in XML as follows.

**Class CreateList:**

```
public class CreateList
{
    public List<string> createListBuild()
    {
        var itemsList = new List<string> { "item1", "item2", "item3" };

        return itemsList;
    }
}
```

**Class ConfigWrapper:**

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "", ElementName = "collection")]
public class ConfigWrapper
{
    [XmlElement("item")]
    public List<string> Items { get; set; }
}
```

**Class WriteReadList:**

```
public class WriteReadList
{
    // Запись в XML
    public void WriteXML(List<string> itemsList)
    {   
        var cfgIn = new ConfigWrapper { Items = itemsList };
        var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ConfigWrapper));
        //string fileContent = "ListXML";
        // string fileContent = @".\ListXML.xml";
        string fileContent = @".\ListXML.xml";

        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            xs.Serialize(sw, cfgIn);
            fileContent = sw.ToString();
            // Console.WriteLine(fileContent);
        }
    }

    public void ReadXML(string fileContent)
    {
        ConfigWrapper cfgOut = null;

        using (var sr = new StringReader(fileContent))
        {
            var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ConfigWrapper));

            cfgOut = xs.Deserialize(sr) as ConfigWrapper;
            // cfgOut.Dump(); //view in LinqPad
            // if (cfgOut != null)
            // yields 'item2'
            // Console.WriteLine(cfgOut.Items[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

I implement the logic with the following buttons:

```
List<string> listWork;
CreateList createList;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listWork = createList.createListBuild();
}

// Сохранить в XML
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Конфигурация обёртки
    ConfigWrapper config = new ConfigWrapper();
    config.Items = listWork;

    WriteReadList writeReadList = new WriteReadList();
    writeReadList.WriteXML(config.Items);
}
```

I can't make the code work
How to do the right thing?
How to make `List<string>` saved / read from an XML file that is located next to the "* .exe" project file?
Or how to do it more easily?

Comment: How is it not working, specifically?

Comment: What *specifically* doesn´t work as you expect? Do you get an exception? Or any unexpected results?

Comment: @mjwills There are no errors.
No XML file is created

Comment: @HimBromBeere There are no errors.
No XML file is created

Answer (score 0):

You must pass the full path of the xml file when using `StringWriter`

For example:

```
//get path of the .exe
string executableLocation = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location); 

//Combine the name of the xml file to get the path of the xml
string xmlPath = Path.Combine(executableLocation, "ListXML.xml");

using (var sw = new StringWriter(xmlPath))
{
     xs.Serialize(sw, cfgIn);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not saving it to the file at all, try this:

```
string filePath = @".\ListXML.xml";

using (var sw = new StringWriter())
{
     xs.Serialize(sw, cfgIn);
     using (var fs = new StreamWriter(filePath))
     {
          fs.Write(sw.ToString());
     }
}
```